# CancellationTokenRegistration.Dispose in Async Task

Tags: c#, asynchronous, task, dispose, cancellation

I am making a `SocketExtender` class which will provide `async/await Task` extension methods to the `Socket` class. In my extension methods I am adding is the ability to cancel a `Socket` operation, such as `ConnectAsync`, `ReceiveAsync`, or `SendAsync` via a `CancellationToken` parameter.

Doing some reading on the optimal way to do this, I have decided to wrap the calls in `TaskCompletionSource<T>` and pass back a `Task` for the operation.

For example, I want to wrap the `BeginReceive` and `EndReceive` APM methods into the following `Task`-based method:

```
public static Task<int> ReceiveAsync(this Socket socket, byte[] buffer, int offset, int count, SocketFlags flags, CancellationToken token) 
{
  var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<int>();

  socket.BeginReceive(buffer, offset, count, flags, result => 
  {
    try
    {
      var bytesReceived = socket.EndReceive(result);
      tcs.SetResult(bytesReceived);
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
      if(token.IsCancellationRequested)
        tcs.SetCanceled();  // <- Yes, this is a typo in the .NET framework! :)
      else
        tcs.SetException(ex);
    }

  });

  return tcs.Task;
}
```

**NOTE**: The above method does *not* actually implement cancellation! Yes, it will handle it, but it will not cause the `Socket` to actually cancel the operation. So I need the `CancellationToken` to trigger a `Socket.Close()` call, via `token.Register()`. No biggie, but the question becomes *how* do I properly dispose of the `CancellationTokenRegistration` object returned?

Here is my first thought:

```
public static Task<int> ReceiveAsync(this Socket socket, byte[] buffer, int offset, int count, SocketFlags flags, CancellationToken token) 
{
  var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<int>();

  using(token.Register(socket.Close))  // <- Here we are ensuring disposal of the CTR
  {
    socket.BeginReceive(buffer, offset, count, flags, result => 
    {
      try
      {
        var bytesReceived = socket.EndReceive(result);
        tcs.SetResult(bytesReceived);
      }
      catch(Exception ex)
      {
        if(token.IsCancellationRequested)
          tcs.SetCanceled();  // <- Yes, this is a typo in the .NET framework! :)
        else
          tcs.SetException(ex);
      }
    });
  }

  return tcs.Task;
}
```

**However**, my question is that will the `CancellationTokenRegistration` be disposed of via `using` before the asynchronous call completes? My first instinct wants to say **yes**, because the `socket.BeginReceive` call will not block and return immediately, causing the `using` statement to clean up once the method returns `tcs.Task`.

But then again, maybe the C# compiler 'understands' what I am doing and will see there's an anonymous method executing in a child scope and some black magic will take place to make it work the way I want.

Do I even need to care about disposing of the `CancellationTokenRegistration` here? Should I keep a reference to it and call `Dispose()` in the `finally` block instead? Or will this work as I want it to as is?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> tcs.SetCanceled();  // <- Yes, this is a typo in the .NET framework! :)

Actually, it's an oddity in the U.S. version of the English language. British (and other) Englishes would use `Cancelled`, but U.S. English uses `Canceled`. Note that `Cancellation` always uses two `l`'s in every version of the English language.

> So I need the CancellationToken to trigger a Socket.Close() call, via token.Register()

I disagree. The convention for cancellation is that *only that operation* is cancelled. So if you had a `Send` operation that took a cancellation token, I would be surprised to find the semantics of send cancellation also faults any `Receive` operations and further makes the entire socket unusable.

> will the CancellationTokenRegistration be disposed of via using before the asynchronous call completes?

Yes. There's no magic understanding on the compiler's part here.

> Do I even need to care about disposing of the CancellationTokenRegistration here? Should I keep a reference to it and call Dispose() in the finally block instead? Or will this work as I want it to as is?

I would recommend not using a `CancellationToken` in the individual operation calls at all. It is logically an object-level cancellation, so creating a separate class and passing it into the constructor is a more proper design IMO. But if you insist, the `finally` block sounds like a good approach.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! Upon further research it would indeed seem that it is not a typo. Ah what a quirky language English can be!

As for the `CancellationToken` usage, I do see your point. It makes little sense to use it versus just closing the `Socket`. Perhaps with `Connect` or `Accept` it makes sense, but not `Send` or `Receive`.

The real question was more about the scope of `using` in this case and if the object would be disposed prematurely, which it seems is the case. Thanks again!

Comment: One solution would be to register an on-canceled continuation for the `Task` you are returning.  Just insert this before your return statement:  `tcs.Task.ContinueWith(_ => socket.Close(), TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnCanceled)`.

Comment: @MikeStrobel: You still have the problem that cancelling a read would close the entire socket, not just cancel that read.

Comment: @StephenCleary True, but if you abort any socket operation, you likely end up with a partially read or written (and therefore invalid) data stream, which probably renders the connection useless.